# Is it possible to define type alias to constexpr function

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr, type-alias

In C++11 or C++14, I'm trying to define a type alias to a constexpr function.

I tried:

```
#include <iostream>
constexpr int foo(int i, int j) { return i + j; }
using TConstExprFunction  = constexpr int (*)(int i, int j);

int main() {
  TConstExprFunction f = foo;
  constexpr int i = f(1, 2);
  std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```

But it fails to compile with g++ and clang++.

g++:
`error: expected type-specifier before 'constexpr'`

clang++:
`error: type name does not allow constexpr specifier to be specified`

I have to do as below to make it compile

```
#include <iostream>
constexpr int foo(int i, int j) { return i + j; }
using TConstExprFunction  = int (*)(int i, int j);

int main() {
  constexpr TConstExprFunction f = foo;
  constexpr int i = f(1, 2);
  std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```

From clang++'s error message, it seems I can NOT using `constexpr` for type name.

So, is it possible to define a type alias to a constexpr function; If yes, how?

Comment: Just like you cannot use `static` there...

Comment: "*So, is it possible to define a type alias to a constexpr function*" You can have a type alias for one. You just can't call a function as though it were a compile-time constant expression through one. So the effect you probably want is impossible.

Comment: @MarcGlisse it makes sense.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the C++ standard *7.1.5/p8 The `constexpr` specifier [dcl.constexpr]* (**Emphasis Mine**):

> **The `constexpr` specifier has no effect on the type of a `constexpr`
>   function** or a `constexpr` constructor.

Also from *7 Declarations [dcl.dcl]*:

> ```
> alias-declaration:
> using identifier attribute-specifier-seqopt = defining-type-id ;
> ```

`constexpr` specifier is not part of a function's type. Consequently, you can't do:

```
using TConstExprFunction  = constexpr int (*)(int i, int j);
```

Since after a `using TConstExprFunction  =` a type is expected.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot define a type alias to a constexpr function.

Comment: Is there any specific reason why C++ standard does not support this?